# How to display alert message when SQL COMMAND return null? ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want that when `SqlCommand` returns zero result or `null`, then show alert message. I try but it always giving me

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Here is my code

ASPX.CS

```
public void gettable()
{
    string user = Session["name"].ToString();

    SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=LIFE_WELL;Initial Catalog=db_compiler;Integrated Security=True");
    //string db = Session["value"].ToString();

    string db = Session["value"].ToString();

    SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand("SELECT Database_id from Create_db WHERE Database_Name='" + db + "'", cnn);

    cnn.Open();

    string dbid = cmd3.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

    SqlCommand cmd4 = new SqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT (Table_Name) from tbl_field WHERE Database_id=" + dbid + "", cnn);
    string tbl_name = cmd4.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd4);
    da.Fill(dt);

    if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
    {
        Response.Write("<Script>alert('" + Server.HtmlEncode("No Tables Found") + "')</Script>");
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            cnn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: which line gives you such error?

Comment: red line error show in output  `Line 34: string tbl_name = cmd4.ExecuteScalar().ToString();`

Comment: which means the query `"SELECT DISTINCT (Table_Name) from tbl_field WHERE Database_id=" + dbid + ""` give you `null` Could you please check the value of `dbid` and is there any database with that id?

Comment: yess `dbid` have `id` I'm sure but `table` query return null

Comment: try this : `WHERE Database_id='" + dbid + "'"` in that query

Comment: I'm also using `"SELECT DISTINCT (Table_Name) from tbl_field WHERE Database_id=" + dbid + "",` and in above `sql-coomand` i have `database-name` so where can i get `dbid`??

Comment: I try but same problem occur.Here is output [LINK](https://s31.postimg.org/i14hebfaz/Snap_2016_06_26_at_21_55_03.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
if (dt == null || dt.Rows.Count <= 0)
{
 Response.Write("<Script>alert('No Tables Found')</Script>");
 return;
}
```

also replace your code as

```
string tbl_name = Convert.ToString(cmd4.ExecuteScalar());
```

Comment: Why there is  a `return;` is that necessary?

Comment: This code still throws Same exception, if `dt` is null

Comment: some time client side alert not shown , because control is going on , that's why  it is use to return it ,

Comment: i try this but it also giving me `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` at red line error show in output `Line 34: string tbl_name = cmd4.ExecuteScalar().ToString();`

Comment: try with this   string tbl_name = Convert.ToString(cmd4.ExecuteScalar());

Comment: and get just first record from db SELECT DISTINCT TOP 1 (Table_Name) from tbl_field

Comment: Thanks..It's working now when i use `string tbl_name = Convert.ToString(cmd4.ExecuteScalar());`

Comment: @NazirUllah : your answer and question are not related, Op marked it as accepted based on the suggestions in the comments.  so you have to edit the post and include the lines in the comments to make it perfect. And also care to explain while answering questions

Answer (score 1):

`ExecuteScalar` only returns one value. You have to make sure your query only returns that value.

> use ExecuteReader

gives you a data reader back which will allow you to read all of the columns of the results a row at a time.

An example would be pulling profile information for one or more users.

> SELECT * FROM pro WHERE id = '123456'

Answer (score 1):

Here is my suggestions:

1. Data binding is one thing, display message is another. You should do data boning first, then display any message to users.
2. Do remember to close DB connection, or it will be a disaster.
3. I don't think you have to data binding in a loop, just do it one time.
4. You can refer "registerstartupscript" in MSDN.